# Why do some tokens have a Max Supply value on CMC while others do not?

Tags: tokens

Tokens like [EOS](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/eos/) and [Populous](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/populous/) have a max supply value on coinmarketcap while others like [vechain](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/vechain/) only have a total supply. what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOS Token Distribution hasn't finished yet, you can check it on their official site: [EOS site](https://eos.io/)

---

By taking EOS as an example, some tokens may have not finished distribution and hence they have total supply of tokens already distributed and the maximal total supply which they can reach.

Comment: No sure how this answers the question

Comment: @code511788465541441 some tokens may have not finished distribution and hence they have total supply of tokens already distributed and the maximal total supply which they can reach.

Comment: So a token having max supply means it hasn't finished distributing? Also, why do the ones that finished not have max supply like bitcoin has both max supply and total supply

Comment: @code511788465541441 yes, it hasn't finished. Can you pleasae elaborate on your last question?

Comment: My last question was, why doesn't the max supply stay even after the distribution has completed. We see both max supply and total supply for coins like bitcoin so why don't we see both values for tokens

Comment: @code511788465541441 we can say that Bitcoin in some sence still hasn't fully distributed it's bitcoins. There was no public bitcoin distribution, all the bitcoins were mined.

Comment: @code511788465541441 btw I was using word "distribution" generally, not only crowdsale.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Final question, does this mean that vechain for example will only ever have 800million tokens?

Comment: @code511788465541441 I haven't seen their contract code, so being abstract, if the contract doesn't have any functionality to increase or change its total supply it will forever stay fixed.